# Not able to open file in Fileoutputstream only in case file is in sd card

Tags: java, android, android-sdcard, randomaccessfile

Below is my SD card path of a start.mp4 file. I am able to get this file in read mode but not able to open in rw mode. I have given run time permissions also. 
It throws a exception:

> /storage/3263-6232/piyush/Download/start.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)

This is the  Code:

```
//This is the sd-card path of the file which needs to be edited

String sdCardPath = "/storage/3263-6232/piyush/Download/start.mp4"; 
File file = new File(sdCardPath );
try{

RandomAccessFile rfs = new RandomAccessFile(file, "rw");

rfs.seek(file.length());
rfs.close();

} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
In the above code I have taken sdcardpath to a file which exists in sdcard. Than after that whenever I tried to open that file in outputstream using RandomAccessFile it gives FilenotFound Exception:

/storage/3263-6232/piyush/Download/start.mp4: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Comment: "I am able to get this file in read mode but not able to open in rw mode" -- since you do not have read/write access to arbitrary files on [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html) on Android 4.4+, this is not surprising. However, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and you have not asked a question.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using android 6 and above you should make a run time permission request 
like that :

```
    private void requestPermission() {

    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);

    }
```

and your onCreate :

```
public void onCreate(){
requestPermission();
}
```